# marionette collection event not firing

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, marionette

Marionette collectionEvents are not firing when the collection is defined inside the initialize function. 
ex:

```
  collectionEvents: {
    update: 'onCollectionUpdate',
    change: 'onCollectionChange',
    error: 'onCollectionError',
  },

initialize(opts) {
    this.collection = new ListCollection({...});
}
```

but it works fine when the collection is defined as a property on the compositeView class

```
  collection: new ListCollection({...}),
  collectionEvents: {
    update: 'onCollectionUpdate',
    change: 'onCollectionChange',
    error: 'onCollectionError',
  },
```

Is there a reason for this I need to define the collection in the initialize function, because i have data being passed to the constructor that the collection needs

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass in an empty collection to the view so that event bindings happen properly while creating view instance, then populate data in collection. Or just pass in collection including data.

```
const view = new CollectionView({
   collection: new ListCollection(/*data you pass to initialize*/),
});
```

or in view's `initialize`

```
initialize(opts) {
  this.collection.reset(options.data);
}
```

I wouldn't expect marionette to track when you are adding `collection` property to view at random point in time and then create event bindings accordingly.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by doing this.delegateEvents() in the initialize. Do you know between the solution that you mentioned and by doing delegateEvents which would be the right way?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use `this.delegateEvents()` because it's more of an internal method and we would be calling it twice (one by marionette while creating view instance then one by us in initialize) I'd just get the first call recognise the collection...